# How to implement html5 pattern to validate input that contains specific letters?

Tags: regex, html

I would like to implement an HTML5 input pattern to validate if input text contains the `- (` characters. There can be characters before and after this text.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTML5 input pattern is basically a **regular expression**, akin to the ones used in JavaScript.

In your case, you want to have a regexp that matches the characters '-(' anywhere in the word:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\.*\-\(\.*">
```

A brief explanation

- `\.` matches **any character**, `*` means it will match **zero or more times**
- `\-\(` matches '-(' **exactly once**, the backslashes are needed because both - and ( are special characters
- `\.*` is like the one in the beginning and will match **any following characters zero or more times**

You can test this regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fL2eU9/1), the  highlighted lines are the ones matching the regexp provided.

#### From the [MDN doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#pattern)

> #### pattern
>
> A regular expression that the control's value is checked against. The
> pattern must match the entire value, not just some subset. Use the
> title attribute to describe the pattern to help the user. This
> attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text,
> search, tel, url or email; otherwise it is ignored. The regular
> expression language is the same as JavaScript's. The pattern is not
> surrounded by forward slashes.

You can also use the [MDN page about regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as reference for creating input patterns, since the syntax is the same.

Also, you can find lots of regular expressions to validate various inputs at [HTML5Pattern](http://html5pattern.com/)

Comment: I get the concept of regex now. I implemented what i want by a different approach however it was useful thank you.

Comment: The `.` character should not be preceded by a backslash if you want it to match any character. If preceded by a backslash it will only represent the period (`.`) character itself and no other characters. Also, `.` matches any character _except_ line-breaks.